# Node JS error when returning data from mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this function

```
const run = async () => {
await LOLUserData.LOLUserData(3)
const LOLUserDataResult = await LOLUserData.LOLUserData()
console.log(LOLUserDataResult)
  await app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Arena Gaming Server is listening on port ${PORT}!`)
  })
}
```

which sends data to this function on startup

```
 //=============================================================================
// [Mongoose] Get Active Sessions users data [userId, IGN, LOLSummonerId, LOLRegion] {Step (2)} {League of Legends Tracking}
//=============================================================================
const User = require('../../models/user')


const getLOLUserData = (userId) => {
    // Get User data if (valid userId & IGN exsists)
    User.findOne({'userId': userId, $and: [ { IGN: { $ne: '' , $exists: true} } ]})
    .then(user => {
        return ( [
            user.userId,
            user.IGN,
            user.LOLRegion,
            user.LOLSummonerId
        ])
    } )
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })

  };

exports.LOLUserData = getLOLUserData
```

The `const LOLUserDataResult = await LOLUserData.LOLUserData()
console.log(LOLUserDataResult)` 
Should return the array from the previous function but instead i get an error

> `TypeError: Cannot read property 'userId' of null`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `User.findOne()` is not finding a record that matches your query. The query successfully executes, but finds no results. The promise resolves to `null`, indicating no record was found. Your `then()` callback runs, and tries to access `user.userId`, which is `null.userId`, which throws the exception.

In your `then()` callback, you should probably have something like this, to protect against getting no results.

```
.then(user => {
    if (user) {
        return [
            user.userId,
            user.IGN,
            user.LOLRegion,
            user.LOLSummonerId
        ]
    } else {
        return [] // or whatever makes sense.
    }
} )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. the record exists if I do console.log instead of the return all the data will appear. The problem is i think the nested return isn't working

Comment: To return a value from an async call, [look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323). But the only way that you would get the error message you posted, from the code you posted, is if the variable `user` was `null`, which is what that error is telling you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was adding a callback argument and returning it

```
    const getLOLUserData =  (userId, callBack) => {
    // Get User data if (valid userId & IGN exsists)
    User.findOne({'userId': userId, $and: [ { IGN: { $ne: '' , $exists: true} } ]})
    .then(user => {

            let result =  [
                user.userId,
                //user.IGN,
                user.LOLRegion,
                user.LOLSummonerId
            ]
            return callBack(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
    })
  };
```

And in app.js I can use it like this

```
    await LOLUserData.LOLUserData(3, async (result) => {
    console.info(result)
})
```